# How to update a node in Firebase if I don't know its key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase DB, I have a list of nodes with auto-generated keys.

```
"visitors" : {
"-KTmRYgWJkT2nq4i1S1D" : {
  "firstname" : "Jsdfa",
  "lastname" : "Jsdfa",
  "visitorId" : "123"
},
"-KTnUbLCtvdeA6G4p5Xh" : {
  "firstname" : "Jsdfadf",
  "lastname" : "Jfasdgf",
  "visitorId" : "124"
},
"-KToFT1rWLuw6ZbS_xGU" : {
  "firstname" : "Jdfadfa",
  "lastname" : "Jsdfad",
  "visitorId" : "125"
}
}
```

Firstly, I found a node that needs to be updated, to do this I used following code:

```
[[_ref child:@"visitors"] queryOrderedByChild:@"visitorId"] queryEqualToValue:@(visitorId)]
```

And then I need to update it or just delete it. [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) says that to do this, I need to have a node key.

And that is the problem. I have tried to find a way how to fetch this key, but without any success, I can't find any information about it. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'visitorId' that you have is the required Node Key.

To delete this node, use:

```
[[[_ref child:@"visitors"] child:@(visitorId)] removeValue];
```

To update this node, use:

```
 [[[_ref child:@"visitors"] child:@(visitorId)] updateChildValues:(dictionary)];
```

Here, dictionary is a nonnull NSDictionary type, you can pass your values to update in this object as a key-value pair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is it possible somehow to update a node with auto-generated key?

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example of what you really want to achieve ?
To update a node, it is necessary to have the full path to that node.
Do you want to insert a new node with auto-generated key and then update its values ?